# networking issue on ubuntu server 20.04

Tags: 20.04

i have a strange problem with my network. i host Minecraft servers for me and my kids and i recent updated from ubuntu 16.04 to 20.04 most of my stuff went across without a hiccup and last week their was some security updates. applied them did a restart and now no one can remote connect to my Minecraft servers and i cant even locally direct connect to them either. otherwise networking is fine i can ssh to anything just nothing outside of my 192.168.1.1 can be remote accessed.

i have never experienced this i have no idea on what logs to search. i can only presume something was updated and got a new config and now has a conflicting error but nothing i can see hasn't loaded or isn't loading.

both machines run ubuntu 20.04 all were fresh installs.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. It is not clear what you mean by 1.1. Is it 192.168.1.1? Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1278387/edit).

Comment: You need to add details about your network topology - machines, subnets, etc. As it is your question doesn't contain enough detail to be able to help you, which is why you haven't been receiving answers.

Answer (score 1):

so i found my problem.

it was binding my server to enp5s0 (192.168.1.165) not enp4s0 (192.168.1.5) so i edited my dhcpd.conf and gave it a static ip and everything is back up and running.